# JBehave getting started issues BeforeAndAfterSteps

Tags: jbehave

I am new to JBehave having started to use it yesterday.

There seems to be a typo in the getting started pages I hope someone
can help with.

In "Developing Stories' section the example of configuration has the line:

addSteps(new InstanceStepsFactory(new TraderSteps(), new
BeforeAndAfterSteps()).createCandidateSteps());

However, there is no class called BeforeAndAfterSteps. The nearest I
found was BeforeOrAfterSteps but it requires parameters in the
constructor and I'm not sure what to use.

Thanks

Comment: This is my mistake. The Steps instances are created by you and added in.

Answer (score 0):

Correct - the InstanceStepsFactory takes your POJOs with JBehave annotated methods and creates Steps out of them.  There are also StepsFactories that can create the Steps classes from a container (Pico, Guice, Spring or Weld).

Comment: and the code on the website doesn't always match the code in the examples - but there are LOTS of examples to help with.  Also the user email list is updated lots faster than StackOverflow.